# Sending emails by workflow - Sharepoint

Tags: workflow, email, incoming-email

I tried to send an email, by workflow, but not all are delivered to my mail.

I make identical Lists, and they always come to the list, but not always to my email.

Sometimes it comes one After 3 sent and sometimes 2 comes after 3 sent mails.

Comment: I don't know if it is the same for workflow emails, but all alerts email do get send out by a timer job that goes every 10 minutes.

Comment: Ok I find out. It was a error on Echange serwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a error in Exchange Server. The Echange Server can't manage to send a lot of emails, wchich I tried to send. I sended to much emails for my Echange Server, and it not can manage with sending me a lot of amails. I don't know Why, but they was on Echange bufor, but not sending

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: I aded a answer :)